# In Angular how to intercept and change content from ng-content?

Tags: javascript, angular, intercept

In Angular, how can I intercept a content coming inside a Component through ng-content and change it before it get's rendered and added inside the ng-content element?

Using fake code, this is what I would like to achieve:

```
@component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  tempalte: 'My component content: <pre><code><ng-content></ng-content></code></pre>'
})
export class MyComponent {

  @NgContent() passedContent;

  constructor() {
    let txt = this.passedContent.nativeElement.innerHTML;
    txt = this.htmlEntities(txt);
    this.passedContent.nativeElement.innerHTML = txt;
  }

  htmlEntities() {
    // convert HTML code to HTML entities
  }

}
```

---

The usage would be:

```
<app-my-component ngNonBindable>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items">{{ item.name }}</li>
  </ul>
</app-my-component>
```

---

The final result would show the code as it is:

```
  My component content: 
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items">{{ item.name }}</li>
  </ul>
```